# Postgresql COPY CSV ERROR: extra data after last expected column

Tags: database, postgresql, csv

I'm trying to import the data from http://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/zip-code-database. A subset of the data looks like this:

```
"zip","type","primary_city","acceptable_cities","unacceptable_cities","state","county","timezone","area_codes","latitude","longitude","world_reg$
"00501","UNIQUE","Holtsville",,"I R S Service Center","NY","Suffolk County","America/New_York","631","40.81","-73.04","NA","US","0","384",
"00544","UNIQUE","Holtsville",,"Irs Service Center","NY","Suffolk County","America/New_York","631","40.81","-73.04","NA","US","0","0"
```

The postgresql command I running is this:

```
copy development.zip_codes FROM '/tmp/zip_code_database.csv' WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;
```

And the result is this:

```
ERROR: extra data after last expected column
SQL state: 22P04
Context: COPY zip_codes, line 2: ""00501","UNIQUE","Holtsville",,"I R S Service Center","NY","Suffolk County","America/New_York","631"..."
```

What am I doing wrong with the import?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works like a charm, here ...

```
DROP TABLE zipcodes CASCADE;
CREATE TABLE zipcodes
        ( id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , zzip varchar NOT NULL UNIQUE
        , ztype varchar
        , primary_city varchar
        , acceptable_cities varchar
        , unacceptable_cities varchar
        , state varchar
        , county varchar
        , ztimezone varchar
        , area_codes varchar
        , latitude varchar
        , longitude varchar
        , world_region varchar
        , country varchar
        , decommissioned varchar
        , estimated_population varchar
        , notes varchar
        ); 

COPY zipcodes (zzip,ztype,primary_city
     , acceptable_cities,unacceptable_cities
     , state,county,ztimezone,area_codes 
     , latitude,longitude,world_region,country
     , decommissioned,estimated_population,notes )
FROM '/tmp/zip_code_database.csv'
        WITH CSV HEADER delimiter ','
        ;
```

Result:

```
DROP TABLE
CREATE TABLE
COPY 42522
```

(maybe the OP has CR/CRLF problems ?)

Comment: The column contents seem to be shifted WRT the headers, stating with the unacceptable--state column; you might need to shuffle the columns a bit ...

Comment: Note: I needed the explicit namelist because I had added the serial `id` column. The explicit list will also make it possible to shuffle the items.

Comment: WRT? What does that mean? I was also trying to make the zipcode a primary key in my example, but you are using serials.

Comment: Oops, I screwed up: I accidently read in the `id` serial, too. UPDATED