# How to successfully import Excel CSV to postgreSQL?

Tags: excel, postgresql, csv

I was able to import two tables using this method but it's not working for the third table. When I run the query it doesn't show error just shows blank.

[Postgresql COPY CSV ERROR: extra data after last expected column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20301646/postgresql-copy-csv-error-extra-data-after-last-expected-column)

I got the format from above.

```
CREATE TABLE GrossNewHomeSales
        (ID varchar not null primary key, nhs_transaction_id varchar not null unique,   
         nhs_week_ending varchar,   nhs_sale_date varchar,  nhs_owner_name varchar,
         nhs_owner_age varchar, nhs_address varchar,    nhs_sf varchar, nhs_realtor_sale varchar,   
         nhs_realtor_name varchar,  nhs_realtor_office varchar, nhs_prev_zip varchar, nhs_employment varchar
);

COPY GrossNewHomeSales (ID, nhs_transaction_id, nhs_week_ending,    nhs_sale_date,
                    nhs_owner_name, nhs_owner_age,  nhs_address,    nhs_sf,
                    nhs_realtor_sale,   nhs_realtor_name,   nhs_realtor_office, nhs_prev_zip,
                    nhs_employment
)                    
FROM
'C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\data\GrossNewHomeSales.csv'
WITH CSV HEADER DELIMITER ',';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL is probably expecting UTF8 encoding for the file, but since you created the file on Windows, it is not. You have 2 choices:

1. Save the file with UTF8 encoding.

   > Should be as simple as opening the CSV in notepad (or equivalent) and saving with the proper (UTF8) encoding.
2. Specify the proper encoding in the `COPY` command.

   > Example: `ENCODING 'WIN1257'`

Here is a list of what PostgreSQL supports:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/multibyte.html